# Creation of a polynomial function from old and new coordinate system pairs

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, interpolation, utm, stereographic

I have data points in the old Roussilhe Stereographic coordinate system of Suriname (u,v), I have the same data points also in WGS84 UTM21N coordinates (x,y). I want to create a polynomial approximation conversion function f(u,v)=(x,y) for use in excel for people who do not have access to geodetic software.

I have access to the tools of proj.org to generate as many points as needed. How do I create a polynomial function from these point pairs (u,v,x,y) ? 5 meter accuracy would be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: If third order polynomials are enough, you can use GeoEasy (open source) to make a least squares estimation for transformation parameters and save them to a text file. See https://github.com/zsiki/GeoEasy